# VS2010 - Wpf editor crashes when using threads

Tags: wpf, multithreading, visual-studio-2010

Is there a way to disable wpf form loading in the designer ?

Whenever I put controls which start separate threads inside my app, the wpf editor crashes my visual studio when loading.

I managed to continue using wpf by ignoring vs2010 error popup, but it's very annoying.

The error message is:

```
Process Name:   devenv.exe : C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe    
Process Architecture:   x86
Exception Code: 0xC0000005
Exception Information:  The thread tried to read from or write to a virtual address for which it does not have the appropriate access.
Heap Information:   Not Present
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to modify your controls to check whether they're in design mode, and, if so, don't do anything.

You should check [`DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(this)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.designerproperties.getisindesignmode.aspx).